# How do you eventBus a bus to communicate updates to a view in a Vue component?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, event-handling, vue-cli-3, event-bus

Listen for custom events for the bus in component b. However, after dispatching events in component a, it accesses component b. the listening function of component b is executed, but `msg` of data function is not updated

Please don't say **Vuex**.

The relevant code is based on **Vue CLi3**

Here code:
Component A:

```
    <template>
      <div>
          Component A
          <button @click="sendMsg">pushB</button>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    import bus from './bus'
    export default {
        methods: {
            sendMsg() {
                bus.$emit('send', 'hello Component B')
                this.$router.push('/bbb')
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

component B：

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>component B：{{ msg }}</p>
    </div>
</template>
<script type="text/javascript">
import  bus  from './bus'
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            msg: 'bbb'
        }
    },
    mounted () {
        bus.$on('send', data => {
            console.log(data)
            console.log(this)
            this.msg = data
        })    
    } 

}
</script>
```

bus.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
export default new Vue()
```

router：

```
const aaa = () => import('@/components/demo/bus/a')
const bbb = () => import('@/components/demo/bus/b')
export default new Router({
  routes: [{
      path: '/aaa',
      component: aaa
    },
    {
      path: '/bbb',
      component: bbb
    }]
})
```

I tried using 'watch' to observe 'msg', but it didn't work.

Can you help me?

If possible, I would like to deeply understand 'bus'

Comment: Probably because you are attaching the listener when Component B is `mounted`, that means it will only be able listen to the event when it(Component B) is mounted. That is not the case when you click on that `pushB` button on component A, as Component B is yet to mount due to route transition.

Comment: When you emit events like so, your components should be parent and child. If they are not one contained one into another and you still want them to communicate (and you don't want to use vuex) you can have another Vue instance that should be event bus implementation.

Comment: @equi I think OP already has a Vue instance for bus and is not using `this.$emit` but `bus.$emit` where `bus` is another Vue instance.

Comment: @AbhishekGupta Thank you for your comment, routing conversion, what do I need to pay attention to?

Comment: In app.js/main.js

window.bus = new Vue();

No need to put it inside another js file

Comment: @BaiClassmateXiao If you wish to pass data around while transition routes consider using query Params. That way even if i do reload at `/bbb` your app will still work as the msg is not part of Query params and not some in memory state.

Comment: @AbhishekGupta Yes, I have thought about this before, but I want to see if bus communication can be realized

Comment: @AbhishekGupta If the page reloads, component b's bus communication callback to a is invalid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work only if both component A and component B are present in the page at the time you are emitting. From the code it seems that you are emitting the value from component A and then navigating to component B and expecting the value there.

What you are doing is something like kicking a ball and then running after it and then picking it only to find that the ball has disappeared. What you need is another person **already present** at that location who picks up the ball.

A solution in this case can be to set the value in localstorage, navigate to the other route and then read the value from localstorage.

If the value you need to pass is a simple value, you can just pass it in query string and then read from $router params in component B.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not work as expected as your are changing route after emitting event from Component A. So it can't be catch by Component B.

You can save the changed value in mixing [look here for mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) or use localstorage. And you can also use query string as stated in previous answer