# How to dispay flash message after redirect vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm creating simple login logout application using vuejs and express. After user register successfully, I redirect them to page login by `this.$router.push('/login')`, and I want to display a flash message like 'Register sucess. Now log in!'

Here is my method

In Register.vue

```
this.$router.push("/login", () => {
  console.log('Register success')
  EventBus.$emit('registerSuccess')
 });
```

In Login.vue

```
 <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" v-if="flashMsg">{{flashMsg}}</div>
    data() {return {flashMsg: ''}}
    created() { 
        console.log('Created component')
        EventBus.$on("registerSuccess", () => {
          console.log('Set flash msg')
          this.flashMsg = "Now log in!"
        });
      },
```

It don't work. EventBus listen the emit but don't set any value to flashMsg.

Console

```
Register success
Set flash msg
Created component
```

Can someone tell me how to do this? Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you initialise EventBus? I can't see that part of the code. That is, `const EventBus = new Vue()`

Comment: Yes, I updated this post.

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58554365/how-do-you-eventbus-a-bus-to-communicate-updates-to-a-view-in-a-vue-component), what you are looking for is not possible because you are changing routes before emitting an event and therefore it cannot be caught.

I suggest you try using localStorage/SessionStorage, Vuex or query strings.

Comment: It did not work. I don't think problem is number of parameter

Comment: I used query /login?msg=registerSuccess and solved this. Thank you