# vue eventbus.$on not update value

Tags: vue.js, event-bus

I want to send username or anything message after login for welcome message in home page.
Inside eventBus.$on console.log write message, but not updating value and outside eventBus console.log write default value.
How can I solve this problem?
Vue version 2.6.12

utils/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
export const EventBus = new Vue()
export default EventBus;
```

Login.vue

```
import { EventBus } from '@/utils'
export default {
name: "Login",

data() {
  return {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    errorMsg: '',
}},

methods: {
    authenticate (){
      this.$store.dispatch('login', { email: this.email, password: this.password })
      .then(() => {EventBus.$emit('login', {name:'hello'}); this.$router.push('/');})
      .catch(error => {this.errorMsg = error.response.data.message})
    },
},
```

Home.vue

```
<p>Welcome, {{userName}}!</p>
<script>
data() {
 return {
   userName: '',
 }
},
created() {
 EventBus.$on('login', data => {this.userName = data.name; console.log('user', data)})
 console.log('this.userName',this.userName)
},
</script>
```

console.log

> user {name: "hello"}

> this.userName

Comment: this may answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58554365/how-do-you-eventbus-a-bus-to-communicate-updates-to-a-view-in-a-vue-component

Comment: @NileshPatel, yes, I think this applies to my question, thank you